# Do some action after addTextChangedListener was added

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have simple following example:

```java
// on UI EditText and Button esists
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(id);
Button b = (Button) findViewById(id);

et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // here simple logic
        if ( ss.length() > 2 ) {
            b.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            b.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that button (b) becomes disabled after first execution of `afterTextChanged` (ss.length() == 0).
But then even if `ss.length() > 2` and line `b.setEnabled(true)` is executed (I can see it in debug mode) button stays disabled.

I don't understand why could it happen.

Comment: Editable parameter is `s` or `ss` ?

Comment: Actually the code works fine to me. The Editable is s not ss

Comment: oh, my mistake (just while typing here an example). Sure it must be `s` and it is in my real project.. so problem still appears

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, you are referring ss instead of s from (Editable s).
Please let me know if you are facing problem after changing ss to s.